# removing null value key-val pair distors order in associative array

Tags: php, arrays

I have this array

```
[1] => Array
    (
        [Assembly required] => Yes
        [Max load (kg)] => 120
        [Product weight (kg)] => 
        [Warranty (years)] => 3
        [Height adjustable] => Yes
        [Lumbar support] => 
        [Back tilt adjustment] => Yes
        [Seat tilt adjustment] => Yes
        [Chair height range (mm)] => 880 - 950
        [Chair seat width (mm)] => 500
        [Chair seat depth (mm)] => 480
        [Chair back height (mm)] => 410
        [Chair back width (mm)] => 420
        [Seat height range (mm)] => 440 - 580
        [AFRDI Approved] => 
        [Optional adjustable arms] => Yes
        [image] => https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1249/7859/files/Chair.png?18135080827462508830
    )
```

The var_dump of above array is

```
         [1]=>
      array(17) {
        ["Assembly required"]=>
        string(3) "Yes"
        ["Max load (kg)"]=>
        string(3) "120"
        ["Product weight (kg)"]=>
        string(0) ""
        ["Warranty (years)"]=>
        string(1) "3"
        ["Height adjustable"]=>
        string(3) "Yes"
        ["Lumbar support"]=>
        string(0) ""
        ["Back tilt adjustment"]=>
        string(3) "Yes"
        ["Seat tilt adjustment"]=>
        string(3) "Yes"
        ["Chair height range (mm)"]=>
        string(9) "880 - 950"
        ["Chair seat width (mm)"]=>
        string(3) "500"
        ["Chair seat depth (mm)"]=>
        string(3) "480"
        ["Chair back height (mm)"]=>
        string(3) "410"
        ["Chair back width (mm)"]=>
        string(3) "420"
        ["Seat height range (mm)"]=>
        string(9) "440 - 580"
        ["AFRDI Approved"]=>
        string(0) ""
        ["Optional adjustable arms"]=>
        string(3) "Yes"
        ["image"]=>
        string(80) "https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1249/7859/files/Chair.png?18135080827462508830"
      }
```

I want to remove the blank value pair from above.

```
  foreach($singlearr as $key=>$value){      
         if(is_null($value) || $value == '')
             unset($singlearr[$key]);
    }
```

This removed key-value pair whose value is null **but it distorted the sequence in following order**.

```
    [1] => Array
    (
        [Assembly required] => Yes
        [Max load (kg)] => 120
        [Warranty (years)] => 3
        [Height adjustable] => Yes
        [Back tilt adjustment] => Yes
        [Chair height range (mm)] => 880 - 950
        [Chair seat width (mm)] => 500
        [Chair seat depth (mm)] => 480
        [Chair back height (mm)] => 410
        [Chair back width (mm)] => 420
        [Seat height range (mm)] => 440 - 580
        [image] => https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1249/7859/files/Chair.png?18135080827462508830
        [Seat tilt adjustment] => Yes
        [Optional adjustable arms] => Yes
    )
```

Result array var_dump form:

```
          [1]=>
      array(14) {
        ["Assembly required"]=>
        string(3) "Yes"
        ["Max load (kg)"]=>
        string(3) "120"
        ["Warranty (years)"]=>
        string(1) "3"
        ["Height adjustable"]=>
        string(3) "Yes"
        ["Back tilt adjustment"]=>
        string(3) "Yes"
        ["Chair height range (mm)"]=>
        string(9) "880 - 950"
        ["Chair seat width (mm)"]=>
        string(3) "500"
        ["Chair seat depth (mm)"]=>
        string(3) "480"
        ["Chair back height (mm)"]=>
        string(3) "410"
        ["Chair back width (mm)"]=>
        string(3) "420"
        ["Seat height range (mm)"]=>
        string(9) "440 - 580"
        ["image"]=>
        string(80) "https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1249/7859/files/Chair.png?18135080827462508830"
        ["Seat tilt adjustment"]=>
        string(3) "Yes"
        ["Optional adjustable arms"]=>
        string(3) "Yes"
      }
```

for eg. in this above result array the `[image]` move above and like so.

Answer (score 3):

you can use

> array_filter()

it will filter out all empty and null values from an array..

[official documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php)

Comment: Use this to remove your null value fields from the array $arr  = array_filter($arr);

Comment: @NaveenKumar @jaimin array_filter() removed the empty i no need to check but it also distorts the previous ordering. I am taking arrays from `CSV` file